# Filter results in seatch output issue

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

I'm using the Google Custom Search API, and for a specific purpose, I need to separate the social sites from the non-social ones. Here's my code:

```
for result in results:
    omitSocials = ['instagram', 'twitter', 'facebook', 'amazon', 'linkedin', 'youtube', 'vimeo', 'google', 'pinterest']
    #omitSocials = ['https://www.instagra', 'https://twitt', 'https://www.faceboo', 'https://www.pinterest', 
                   #'https://business.faceboo', 'https://www.amazon', 'https://m.faceboo', 'https://vimeo', 
                   #'https://www.youtu', 'https://play.google', 'https://support.goog']
    urls = str(result.get('link'))
    for social in omitSocials:
        if social in urls:
            print("="*10, f"Result", "="*10)
            print(result.get('title'))
            print(urls)
            print(result.get('snippet'))
        else:
            pass
```

Output:

```
========== Result ==========
Pinch of Yum (@pinchofyum) • Instagram photos and videos
https://www.instagram.com/pinchofyum/?hl=en
1m Followers, 226 Following, 2435 Posts - See Instagram photos and videos 
from Pinch of Yum (@pinchofyum)
========== Result ========
Pinch of Yum (pinchofyum) on Pinterest
https://www.pinterest.com/pinchofyum/
Pinch of Yum - 985.54k Followers, 446 Following, 54382 pins | Pinch of Yum - a 
food blog with simple, tasty, and (mostly) healthy recipes.
========== Result ==========
Pinch of Yum (@pinchofyum) | Twitter
https://twitter.com/pinchofyum?lang=en
The latest Tweets from Pinch of Yum (@pinchofyum). Simple, tasty, and (mostly) 
healthy recipes. Saint Paul, MN.
========== Result ==========
Pinch of Yum - Home | Facebook
https://www.facebook.com/pinchofyum/
Pinch of Yum, Minneapolis, MN. 354419 likes · 801 talking about this. Simple, 
tasty, and (mostly) healthy recipes. Recipes:...
========== Result ==========
Pinch of Yum
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC9ORxqKBywaO7fgflFJzHRw
Videos from Pinch of Yum - A food blog with simple, tasty, and (mostly) healthy 
recipes. ... A food blog with simple and tasty recipes. https://pinchofyum.com/​.
```

But when I do the same thing for `for social not in urls:`, I'm not getting the result without the social sites.
Every result (including the social ones) is occurring, but 9 times each!
Desired Output:

```
========== Result ==========
Pinch of Yum - A food blog with simple and tasty recipes.
https://pinchofyum.com/
... your food photography4 Behind the Scenes: 5 Time-Saving Tips for Food 
Photography5 Our First Ever Tasty Food Photography Workshop · Pinch of Yum.
========== Result ==========
Recipes - Pinch of Yum
https://pinchofyum.com/recipes
Pinch of Yum is a food blog with hundreds of simple, healthy recipes to fit just 
about any taste or diet. Find all our recipes here!
========== Result ==========
Lindsay Ostrom (@pinchofyum) Profile, Photos & Recipes | The ...
https://thefeedfeed.com/pinchofyum
We like to eat.
https://pinchofyum.tumblr.com/
Jun 22, 2013 ... pinchofyum, a blog on Tumblr. Never miss a post from pinchofyum. Make gifs, 
join group chats, find your community. Only in the app.
========== Result ==========
pinchofyum | Healthy Aperture
https://healthyaperture.com/author/pinchofyum
A unique recipe discovery site curated by registered dietitians helping you find 
the best healthy food blog recipes - including gluten free, vegan and more.
```

This output is the one I want to get, it does not include the socials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your `for` loop and `if` statement with the following. This will check if any of the strings in `omitSocials` is in your current url.

```
if all(social not in urls for social in omitSocials):
    print("="*10, f"Result", "="*10)
    print(result.get('title'))
    print(urls)
    print(result.get('snippet'))
else:
    pass
```

Comment: I wanna get the ones without the socials, your code only gives me the socials, which is what I did too

Comment: Ok in that case, you can use `all` to check `not in` for each of the `social` strings